# Is the product sigma algebra generated by P(R) and P(R) equal to P(R^2)?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Is $P(\mathbb R) \otimes P(\mathbb R) = P(\mathbb R^2)$?
I'm using the tensor notation $\otimes$ to denote the sigma algebra generated by sets of the form {$A \times B$: A, B $\subseteq \mathbb R$}. It's clear that the LHS is a subset of the RHS, but I wasn't sure what the best approach was to prove equality (or inequality).

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $U:=\{(a_\vartheta,b_\vartheta)\mid \vartheta<\kappa\}$ for a $\kappa>\omega$ cardinal and arbitrary but distinct points $(a_\vartheta,b_\vartheta\in\Bbb R)$. Then $U$ is not in the sigma algebra generated by sets of the form $A\times B$.

Comment: Berci, I'm not sure it works for $X$ when $X$ has cardinality equal to continuum. 1) If $X$ is a countable set, then $\mathscr P(X)\otimes \mathscr P(X)=\mathscr P(X^2)$. (This is easy to see) 2) If $X$ has cardinality greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$, then $\mathscr P(X)\otimes\mathscr P(X)\neq \mathscr P(X^2)$. (see, for ex., *Real analysis and probability*, R. N. Dudley, 2002, pg. 123) 3) What about when $\aleph_0< |X|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ ?

Comment: It is known that  $2^{\omega_1}\otimes 2^{\omega_1}=2^{\omega_1\times\omega_1}$, so this answer is not correct. See the references listed [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1691283).